# How do I get the child div which is inside the parent div, go on the first line of the div?

Tags: css, position, display

How do I get the child div which is inside the parent div, go on the first line of the div?
See the picture for what I mean:  [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "first line". Can you make a demo with your current code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: add some relevant code and explain exactly what you want. by default the child div will stay like in the image ( without the margins ) . so what exactly do you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.parentDiv
{
  position: relative;
  /*...*/
}
.childDiv
{
  position: absolute;
  /*...*/
}
```

Basicly that's the CSS. [Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```css
#parent {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    height:300px;
}
#child {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width:220px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#two {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width:100px;
}

.kids {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="width: 250px; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
    
    <div id="child" class="kids">
        <span>child</span>
    </div>
    
  
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to look like in your img just do this :

```css
.parent {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:orange;
}
.child {
  height:50px;
  width:80%;
  background-color:green;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">

</div>
</div>
```

i am VERY curious to see why the downvote ? anyone ?